# Почему два раза выполняется событие клика при закрытии меню?

Tags: javascript, html, css, foreach

делаю раскрывающуюся менюшку по клику, все работает, меню раскрывается, по нажатию вне области меню - закрывается, но есть проблема, что теперь по клику второй раз на кнопку, которая вызывает показ этой меню, она не закрывается. Как исправить то, что проходит два клика из-за цикла forEach?

```js
// для поиска в header
const searchBg = document.querySelector('.search-bg'),
  searchBtnAll = document.querySelectorAll('#searchBtn'),
  headerSearch = document.querySelector('.header__search'),
  headerSeacrhBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.search-bg__select-btn'),
  dropDownMenuSearchContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.search-bg__select-container'),
  searchInput = document.createElement('input'),
  dropDownMenuSearch = document.createElement('div'),
  searchInputPlaceholder = document.querySelectorAll('.search-bg__span');
// открытие поиска по кнопке
function searchFilter() {

  openSearchBgBtn();
  // открытие меню поиска
  function openSearchBgBtn() {
    searchBtnAll.forEach(btn => {
      btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (!searchBg.classList.contains('active') && e.target !== btn) {
          searchBg.classList.add('active');
          searchBg.classList.remove('remove');
        } else {
          searchBg.classList.add('remove');
          searchBg.classList.remove('active');
        }
      });
      closeSearchFilter();
    });
  }
  // закрытие меню при клике на свободную область
  function closeSearchFilter() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
      if (!searchBg.contains(e.target)) {
        searchBg.classList.add('remove');
        searchBg.classList.remove('active');
      }
      console.log(e.target);
    })
  }
}
searchFilter();
```

```css
.search-bg {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
          box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 130px;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 25px 15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  z-index: 9999;
  opacity: 0;
}

.search-bg.active {
  top: 140px;
  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 1;
}

.search-bg.remove {
  top: 130px;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.search-bg__select-container + .search-bg__select-container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.search-bg__select-container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 230px;
  position: relative;
}
.search-bg__select-container::after {
  background: url(../img/icons/selectArrow.svg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0.543;
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.1s ease-out;
  width: 24px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.search-bg__select-btn {
  width: 100%;
  background: none;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #bcbcbc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.search-bg__select-btn::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #bcbcbc;
}
.search-bg__select-btn::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #bcbcbc;
}
.search-bg__select-btn:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #bcbcbc;
}
.search-bg__select-btn::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #bcbcbc;
}
.search-bg__select-btn::placeholder {
  color: #bcbcbc;
}

.search-bg__span {
  color: #bcbcbc;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.search-bg__select-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 60px;
}

.search-bg__select-dropdown.active {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 60px;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
          filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.search-bg__select-dropdown-list {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.search-bg__select-dropdown-item + .search-bg__select-dropdown-item {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.search-bg__select-dropdown-item {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.search-bg__select-dropdown-item:hover {
  color: #fd8223;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <button class="" type="button" id="searchBtn">
            <span class="">
                Открыть меню
            </span>
        </button>
    <!-- меню для поиска -->
<div class="search-bg">
    <div class="search-bg__select-container">
        <button class="search-bg__select-btn" type="button">
            <span class="search-bg__span">
                Категория
            </span>
        </button>
        <!-- <div class="search-bg__select-dropdown">
            <ul class="search-bg__select-dropdown-list">
                <li class="search-bg__select-dropdown-item">Автотовары</li>
                <li class="search-bg__select-dropdown-item">Бытовая техника</li>
                <li class="search-bg__select-dropdown-item">Пример</li>
                <li class="search-bg__select-dropdown-item">Автотовары</li>
                <li class="search-bg__select-dropdown-item">Бытовая техника</li>
                <li class="search-bg__select-dropdown-item">Пример</li>
            </ul>
        </div> -->
    </div>
    <div class="search-bg__select-container">
        <button class="search-bg__select-btn" type="button">
            <span class="search-bg__span">
                Модель
            </span>
        </button>
        <!-- <div class="search-bg__select-dropdown">
            <ul class="search-bg__select-dropdown-list">
                <li class="search-bg__select-dropdown-item">Автотовары</li>
                <li class="search-bg__select-dropdown-item">Бытовая техника</li>
                <li class="search-bg__select-dropdown-item">Пример</li>
                <li class="search-bg__select-dropdown-item">Автотовары</li>
                <li class="search-bg__select-dropdown-item">Бытовая техника</li>
                <li class="search-bg__select-dropdown-item">Пример</li>
            </ul>
        </div> -->
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Событие `mousedown` у document всегда опережает `click` у кнопки. Поэтому меню успевает закрыться, затем снова открывается.

Чтобы всё заработало, нужно сделать две вещи:

1. Заменить `mousedown` на `click` для document
2. Добавить `e.stopPropagation()` в обработчик для кнопки, чтобы событие не дошло до document и не закрыло меню.

Comment: спасибо, благодаря Вам, я узнал еще что-то новое. Хорошего Вам дня и удачи :)